# jQuery return NAN when sum formatted negative value and decimal separator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to sum the value of multiple textbox and display in a another textbox

```
 $(document).on("change", ".charges", function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".charges").each(function () {
            sum += +($(this).val().substring(1));
        });

        $(".sub-total-Of-Charges").val("$ "+sum);           
       
    });
```

It return $ NAN when i enter -ve value which currently formatted to be displayed in a bracket as forexample (100) also when value greater than 1,000 with decimal separator comma. I need help on how to fix it?

Comment: if a negative value is in the input as `(100)` then `"(100).substring(1)`" is `100)` ... which is not a number

Comment: why are you taking `substring(1)` of the number. it will remove the first digit anyway. Is that you wanted for real?

Comment: @Beingnin Oh i was trying to remove $ sign that was also creating a problem

Comment: instead of using substring , use regex to remove commas and brackets except `-` sign.

Comment: `$(this).val().replace(/[^0-9-]/g,'')`

Comment: I tried it still the same, when one the first textbox i entered $5 on the next i entered $10 on the third one i add 44444 = the sum of the three gives me $4459

Comment: you are still using sub string? looks like `44444` loses one digit and becomes `4444`

Comment: I replaced it with your code

Comment: just check this fiddle. it is working properly only https://jsfiddle.net/cty35r7w/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using substring , use regex to remove commas and brackets except `-` sign

```
 $(document).on("change", ".charges", function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".charges").each(function () {
            sum += +($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9-]/g,''));
        });

        $(".sub-total-Of-Charges").val("$ "+sum);           
       
    });
```

Comment: Thank you but this code gives me a weird result, i eneterd $4 in the first textbox and $3 on the second then on `sub-total-Of-Charges` text shows me $707, when i do 4 and 5 = 909

Comment: can u check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cty35r7w/

Comment: yes, i checked that not sure why not working in my case

Comment: something else must be interfering

Comment: check for `$(".charges").length`. Confirm there are no hidden textboxes with values

Comment: No hidden textbox `$(".charges").length` return 12

Comment: any luck finding out the issue?

Comment: Hi @Beingnin still no luck